# How can I get jquery-ui autocomplete suggestions to appear elsewhere on the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've got a textarea with jquery-ui autocompletion working on it.  I'd like the suggestions to appear in a fixed-height area above the textarea, much as the title suggestions appear below the title box here on stackoverflow.

What do I need to add to my page, and what options do I need to pass to the autocomplete function, for this to work?

Comment: you can simply use css to reposition the wrapper of the results as long as you know which one that is :)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is this:

```
var searchbox = $('.ui-autocomplete');  // get autocomplete list
$('.ui-autocomplete').remove();    // remove the original
$('#mydiv').prepend(searchbox);     // prepend to your desire div
```

Then, you should overwrite the class `ui-autocomplete` to adapt to your own design and remove its actual behaviour (changing its position, size, and whatever you want).

Be careful because the first line remove all the autocomplete lists. Happy codding!

Answer (score 0):

I found it worked to do....

```
$('#myInputSelector').autocomplete({
    ....
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").appendTo("#search-results")
        .css("width", "300px")
        .css("height", "100px")
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .css("top", "0px")
        .css("left", "0px");
    },
    .....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `appendTo`, like so

```
$('#the-textarea').autocomplete({
    ...
    appendTo: $('#the-area-above-the-textarea'),
    ...
});
```